# Recreating a C CRC32 algorithm in Python with crcmod

Tags: python, python-2.x, crc32

I'm attempting to decode a Novatel GPS stream in Python, and I have all of the components for the sync, header, and payload sorted, but I cannot replicate the CRC32 used as part of the messages. The algorithm used to generate the CRC appended on the message is written in c as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define CRC32_POLYNOMIAL 0xEDB88320L
//#define CRC32_POLYNOMIAL 0x04C11DB7L

unsigned long CRC32Value(int i)
{
    int j;
    unsigned long ulCRC;
    ulCRC = i;
    for (j = 8; j > 0; j--)
    {
        if (ulCRC & 1)
            ulCRC = (ulCRC >> 1) ^ CRC32_POLYNOMIAL;
        else
            ulCRC >>= 1;
    }
    return ulCRC;
}
unsigned long CalculateBlockCRC32(
    unsigned long ulCount,
    unsigned char *ucBuffer)
{
    unsigned long ulTemp1;
    unsigned long ulTemp2;
    unsigned long ulCRC = 0;
    while (ulCount-- != 0)
    {
        ulTemp1 = (ulCRC >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFFL;
        ulTemp2 = CRC32Value(((int)ulCRC ^ *ucBuffer++ ) & 0xff );
        ulCRC = ulTemp1 ^ ulTemp2;
    }
    return(ulCRC);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char buffer[] = {0xaa, 0x44, 0x12, 0x1c, 0x2a, 0x00, 0x02, 0x20, 0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90, 0xb4, 0x93, 0x05, 0xb0, 0xab, 0xb9, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x45, 0x61, 0xbc, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1b, 0x04, 0x50, 0xb3, 0xf2, 0x8e, 0x49, 0x40, 0x16, 0xfa, 0x6b, 0xbe, 0x7c, 0x82, 0x5c, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x60, 0x76, 0x9f, 0x44, 0x9f, 0x90, 0x40, 0xa6, 0x2a, 0x82, 0xc1, 0x3d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12, 0x5a, 0xcb, 0x3f, 0xcd, 0x9e, 0x98, 0x3f, 0xdb, 0x66, 0x40, 0x40, 0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x03};

    unsigned long crc = CalculateBlockCRC32(sizeof(buffer), buffer);
    cout << hex << crc << endl;
}
```

The result of this is 0x42, 0xdc, 0x4c, 0x48 - which matches the example given in the manual, so that's a nice start.

Whilst I could potentially use this algorithm in the code I am writing I would prefer to remain in Python where possible, so at this point I feel I have two options. I can either translate this into Python myself or hope that there is a built-in Python function or module capable of doing this for me, which is what I have been looking at doing. So far I have found three functions/modules:

- binascii.crc32
- zlib.crc32
- crcmod module

Of these the top two give the same incorrect result and I cannot tell any way of changing settings or specifying arguments which might influence this positively.

crcmod on the other hand has a plethora of settings and predefined functions which I think should be able to do what I am looking for. The format to create the CRC function is as follows:

```
crcmod.mkCrcFun(poly[, initCrc, rev, xorOut])
```

Of of the crucial things I found was there are predefined CRC functions, and the CRC32 version of this matches the results from binascii and zlib:

```
Name    Polynomial  Reversed?   Init-value  XOR-out Check
crc-32  0x104C11DB7 True    0x00000000  0xFFFFFFFF  0xCBF43926
```

So at least that helps me understand where the zlib and binascii variants are coming from in terms of the polynomial used.

I'm convinced that I should therefore be able to generate the same result as the C algorithm using this function, but not being well-versed in C I'm not sure how I do this. The polynomial used in the C algorithm is a reversed representation of the polynomial, so this implies that the settings above should work, but they don't generate the answer above as per the C code.

What am I looking for to determine these settings, is there a module/function which will do this that I haven't seen, or is this not going to work and I should instead just start translating that C into Python myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `crcmod`, you need to add `1` in the front of the polynomial, as the 33rd bit needs to be `1`, otherwise you get an exception saying that the degree must be 8, 16, 24 or 32. This seems to produce your expected output:

```
import crcmod
crc = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x104C11DB7, 0, True, 0)
```

And then this following example should work properly on both Python 2 and 3:

```
value = bytes(bytearray(
    [0xaa, 0x44, 0x12, 0x1c, 0x2a, 0x00, 0x02, 0x20,
     0x48, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x90, 0xb4, 0x93, 0x05,
     0xb0, 0xab, 0xb9, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
     0x45, 0x61, 0xbc, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
     0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1b, 0x04, 0x50, 0xb3,
     0xf2, 0x8e, 0x49, 0x40, 0x16, 0xfa, 0x6b, 0xbe,
     0x7c, 0x82, 0x5c, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x60, 0x76, 0x9f, 
     0x44, 0x9f, 0x90, 0x40, 0xa6, 0x2a, 0x82, 0xc1, 
     0x3d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x12, 0x5a, 0xcb, 0x3f, 
     0xcd, 0x9e, 0x98, 0x3f, 0xdb, 0x66, 0x40, 0x40,
     0x00, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
     0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x0b, 0x00, 0x00,
     0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x03]))

print(hex(crc(value))))
```

prints

```
0x484cdc42
```

Which is the little-endian ordered value of octets `0x42, 0xdc, 0x4c, 0x48`.

Comment: Just to confirm this works with Python 2 and 3 now. Thanks.

Comment: In case you do not want to rely on third-party modules, you can compute the CRC also with zlib: `0xFFFFFFFF ^ zlib.crc32(value, 0xFFFFFFFF)` should also yield the desired result.